# What are lightroom alternatives for netbook with 2gb ram and a atom mobile processor

Tags: photo-editing, software-recommendation, editing

I have an acer switch 10 detachable notbook which has 2gb of ram and Atom Z3735F @1.33GHZ as processor.I want an photo editing software which can come close to adobe lightroom.Please let me know some alternatives.Thank you.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic across most of stack exchange, with the exception of https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Nazib, the reason that product recommendations are off-topic here is that they become obsolete very quickly. If I would recommend "software A" now, in a year time the software might be upgraded such that it no longer can run on 2GB RAM or it might be unavailable alltogether.
Also, you question lacks a bit of prior research. What options have you looked into already?

Comment: Your question might become relevant (to me, not sure what others would think) if you rewrite it along the lines of: "I want to use software X on a machine that barely matches the minimum system specs. What software options should I configure to optimize the software performance?"

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend checking out [RawTherapee](https://rawtherapee.com/). They do mention that you'd  ideally want 4GB of RAM minimum, but they noted that people have been able to run on 2GB before [here](https://rawtherapee.com/2011/08/maximizing-memory-efficiency/).

Also its free, so nice bonus.